# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.mockito.Mockito

Tags: android, android-studio, mockito, dexmaker

I'm trying to run unit test on Android Library project and using mockito 1.9.5 with dexmaker 1.0 & dexmaker -mockito-1.0 jar files.

I am using Android Studio 0.2.6 and whenever I run a test case I end up getting

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.mockito.Mockito exception.
```

I have mentioned the dependencies in build.gradle file as below

```
compile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.0'
compile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.0'
compile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
```

Has anyone encountered this problem before on Android Studio? If you did please share your solutions/fixes.

Thanks

Comment: extract the jar and check if class is present or not

Comment: thanks for the reply.the class is present but still it complains!! no luck yet but will post an update if i solve it.

Answer (score 3):

Cleaning the project from a terminal `gradlew clean` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

if that doesn't work delete .gradle folder inside project, and what's inside build folder.